# Can we use Karate and Rest-Assured in the same project (with gradle)?

Tags: gradle, karate, rest-assured

Can we use Karate on a project where we already used Rest-Assured for API tests and Cucumber with java for mobile and web apps. We use gradle. 
If yes, how we can manage our folders? Where we have to put our Karate runner class? When I run it, it returns

```
"14:53:55.230 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - init test class: class runners.karateTest.TestRunner
No features found at [classpath:features/users/User.feature]
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Refer to the documentation, it has instructions from Gradle and how to call Karate via a Java API if really needed.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628686/143475

Comment: I won't be able to explain maven and gradle basics here. note that exclude *.java will include class files. my recommendation is that you are trying to do too much, you don't seem to be able to get a simple karate hello world working and now you are trying to mix rest-assured. please start simple and don't confuse yourself.