# Karate Java API for Match methods

Tags: karate, rest-assured

**Background:**

I noticed this interesting post on Twitter about a Java API for Karate: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1344290316212342784

I don't have a twitter account so unable to reply - hope you don't mind me asking here instead.

I have used Karate (with the parallel runner, feature files and all) in one work project and it is a joy to use - and a few folks in the workplace are very impressed with the complex JSON assertion. We are achieving a level of JSON response field coverage for that project that is not possible with other frameworks (IMO).

I've now been tasked with improving an older test project which uses JUnit + RESTAssured, but has quite limited field assertions. I am unable to fully convert it to raw Karate (too many tests, not enough time), but I'm keen to explore the possibility of supplementing what is there already with the Karate Java API mentioned in above twitter post.

For example - for an existing test which gets a Response using RESTAssured, it would be nice for me to somehow use the 'contains' method (or any of the methods in Match class) in Karate to assert that response, as it is the best JSON assertion tool I have come across.

**Questions:**

1. Off the bat - is this a practice you would recommend for my use case? Let me know if you think this is an anti-pattern. I ask this because the example here (https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-showcase) is not using RESTAssured to get the response and my use case is a bit different.
2. If its worth exploring - I assume this stuff will be available in v1.0.0? (I see public methods such as *that* are on the develop branch, but couldn't see it on the v1.0.0 github thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm keen to explore the possibility of supplementing what is there already with the Karate Java API mentioned in above twitter post.

That's very interesting and you have got me also thinking about this potentially interesting way to introduce Karate to legacy projects. I do get this question on how to magically migrate existing RA tests a lot.

I would recommend it. You can expect a 0.9.9.RC3 next week that should have all the assertions you want. And the API has been simplified so you don't need to call `isTrue()` etc.

We plan to have better examples (maybe you can help) but for now, use this as a starting point (look at the last test / very end of the file): [`MatchTest.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/MatchTest.java)

If you want to get started now (which I recommend and you can provide more feedback) do take a look at the developer guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Sounds great! Thank you.

Comment: I have a github account and will attempt to contribute some examples.